# Get proper case working directory?

Tags: c++, winapi

To better familiarize myself with C++, I'm redoing an old college OS assignment: program your own shell. I'm using all sorts of `Windows.h` that I've never known existed. So far I've made good progress but I've noticed something about my `cd` implementation and my working directory I get back from `getcwd`.

My `cd` command does some error checking but ultimately it comes down to `chdir(path)`. Say I'm at `C:\` and there exists a folder `FOLDER`. If I use `chdir("folder")` then later when I call `getcwd(dir, FILENAME_MAX)` then I'll get the string `C:\folder` instead of the case correct string `C:\FOLDER`. How can I retrieve the working directory with every folder having the proper case?

Note: When I first start my shell and run my `pwd` command (that solely prints `dir` from my `getcwd` call), I get a path that is properly cased. As soon as I start changing the working directory then the casing always matches my strings instead of the actual folder casing.

Comment: Probably not the solution, but `chdir` and `getcwd` are deprecated. The correct version is `_chdir` and `_getcwd`; I don't suggest using POSIX on Windows, in general, though.

Comment: As a side-note, Windows does not use case-sensitive paths.

Comment: I know it doesn't require case sensitive paths, but in order to really challenge myself, I'm keeping an eye for detail and letting `cmd.exe` set the standard. It's prompt is properly cased, therefore mine will be.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Windows command prompt just uses `GetLongPathName`, which returns the path with appropriate casing (however, it doesn't change the drive letter's casing).

If you want an uppercase drive letter, the `GetShortPathName` function returns the short path with the driver letter capitalized. You can then pass this short path to `GetLongPathName`, which will turn it into a properly cased long path, but this isn't what cmd does.

You can also use `SHGetFileInfo`, but it's not the easiest approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GetFullPathName` API function to return the proper (case correct) path of the current directory, as in the following example:

```
TCHAR tchPath[MAX_PATH];
GetFullPathName(TEXT("."), MAX_PATH, tchPath, NULL);
```